# Web Scraping with __doPostBack

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data (just need the url for each Lego set's page) from https://www.brickeconomy.com/sets/theme/collectable-minifigures but there is pagination on the website using Javascript __doPostBack function. I looked at many other relevant answers to know that I need to look into the POST request to identify the request form data as seen here:

[Screenshot of Request's Form Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBtNP.png)

My code is as follows now:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.brickeconomy.com/sets/theme/collectable-minifigures"
page_content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'html.parser')

VIEWSTATEGENERATOR  = soup.find('input',{'id':'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'}).get('value')
VIEWSTATE  = soup.find('input',{'id':'__VIEWSTATE'}).get('value')

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
data = {  
        "ctl00$ScriptManager1": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlSets$UpdatePanelMain|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlSets$GridViewSets",
        "ctl00$txtSearchHeader2": "",
        "ctl00$txtSearchHeader": "",
        "subthemesorter": "",
        "setsorter": "SetNumberDESC",
        "ctl00$LoginModalUsername": "",
        "ctl00$LoginModalPassword": "",
        "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlSets$GridViewSets",
        "__EVENTARGUMENT": "Page$2",
        "__VIEWSTATE":VIEWSTATE,
        "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, 
        "__ASYNCPOST": 'true'
}

res = requests.post(url, data=data, headers =headers).content
BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser').find_all(class_ = 'mb-5')
```

However, it is still showing the data from the first page. Would appreciate any advice here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were sending post requests to the wrong url. Once I've replaced your existing url with the correct one, the script started to work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base = 'https://www.brickeconomy.com'
start_url = 'http://www.brickeconomy.com/sets/theme/collectable-minifigures'
post_url = 'https://www.brickeconomy.com/sets/theme/sets/theme/collectable-minifigures'

data = {  
    "ctl00$ScriptManager1": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlSets$UpdatePanelMain|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlSets$GridViewSets",
    "ctl00$txtSearchHeader2": "",
    "ctl00$txtSearchHeader": "",
    "subthemesorter": "",
    "setsorter": "SetNumberDESC",
    "ctl00$LoginModalUsername": "",
    "ctl00$LoginModalPassword": "",
    "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlSets$GridViewSets",
    "__EVENTARGUMENT": "Page$2",
    "__ASYNCPOST": 'true'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(start_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

    data['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.find('input',{'id':'__VIEWSTATE'}).get('value')
    data['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = soup.find('input',{'id':'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'}).get('value')

    res = s.post(post_url,data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("table.table > tr h4 > a"):
        inner_url = urljoin(base,item.get("href"))
        print(inner_url)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working now, once I added "s" to "http" in the url.